# Different results when data type is specified as int or float or double

Tags: c

When compiling and running this program why is it that we get "Greater" instead of "Equal"? I checked, when we specify data type as `int` we get "Less" and when specified as `double` we get "Equal". What is the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float g = 9.8;
    if (g == 9.8){
        printf("Equal");
    }
    else if (g < 9.8){
        printf("Less");
    }
    else{
        printf("Greater");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the literal `9.8` has type `double`.

Comment: The decimal value `9.8` can't be represented exactly in binary to start with. The value of the floating point literal `9.8` must be converted to a `float` in the assignment to `g`, but this `double` value will not fit into a `float`. [According to the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p2) it is _implementation-defined_ whether the resulting value is the next smaller value or the next larger value. In the comparisons, this `float` value is converted to a `double`, preserving the value of the `float`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because `int` `truncates` the value, meaning it strips off the decimal part without rounding so turning `9.8` to `int` by `(int) 9.8` gives 9.

When `g` is type `double` it returns `equal` because by default decimal numbers are `double`.

When `g` is a `float` then you have a comparison between a `float` and a `double` which is not good since `double` has more precision points than `float` meaning it could result in mismatch.

*The values used in an expression are considered as double (double precision floating point format) unless a ‘f’ is specified at the end. So the expression “g==9.8” has a double on right side and float which are stored in a single precision floating point format on left side. In such situations float is promoted to double. The double precision format uses more bits for precision than single precision format.*

More [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparison-float-value-c/).

But, if you did this you would get equal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float g = 9.8;

    // Add the f to typecast to float
    if (g == 9.8f) printf("Equal");
    else if (g < 9.8) printf("Less");
    else printf("Greater");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't do floor. it truncates.

Comment: @DanielA.White You are right it does `truncate`. It's correct to say it that way, I will edit, thanks.